# Como alterar o nome do botão caso usuário tenha feito cadastro - LARAVEL?

Tags: php, laravel

Boa noite, gostaria de colocar tipo um aviso no botão caso usuário tenha feito tal cadastro no meu caso tenha feito renovação, usuário entra no card e nota que já fez a inscrição o nome do botão muda e esteja escrito "inscrito"...

--- Controller store que salva, e listar dados e manda os dados para o formulário

```
public function listardados(){
    $matricula = Matricula::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();

    //dd($matricula);
    return view('dashboard.renovacao.teste', compact( 'matricula'));
}

public function store(RenovacaoRequest $request){


    $user = Auth()->user();

    $dados = $request->get('rematricula');

    foreach ($dados as $key => $dado) {

        Renovacao::create($dado);
    }

    return view('dashboard.renovacao.confirmacao', compact ('renovacao'));
}
```

--FORM

```
@extends('layouts.app') @section('content')

<div class="container">
<div class="row">

    <form class="form-horizontal " id="regForm" action="{{route('renovacao.store')}}" method="POST">
        <div class="card-panel white">
            <h4 class="center">Solicitar Renovação</h4>
            <div class="row"></div>
            {{ csrf_field()}}

            <div class="row">
                @if($matricula->count())
                    <right>
                        <a>**Dados Cadastrados**</a>
                    </right>
                    <div class="row"></div>
                    <div class="row"></div>
                    @foreach($matricula as $matric)

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col s6 m6">
                            <div class="input-field {{$errors->has('') ? 'has-error' : ''}} ">
                                <label for="produto">Nome do Pai:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rematricula[{{ $loop->index}}][nomerespo]" value="{{ $matric->nomedopai }}">
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col s6 m6">
                            <div class="input-field {{$errors->has('') ? 'has-error' : ''}} ">
                                <label for="produto">Nome do Aluno(a):</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rematricula[{{ $loop->index}}][nomealuno]" value="{{ $matric->nomealuno }}">
                            </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    @endforeach
                    <div class="col s12 m6">
                        <div class="row"></div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div>
                                <div class="card-panel white ">
                                    <b class="black-text">AVISO? </b></br></br>
                                    <span>• Mensagem de Aviso </span></br></br>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class = "row">
                        <div class="col s12">

                            <a title="Voltar Para Página Principal" class="btn orange darken-4 btn-info left " href="/admin">Voltar
                                <i class="material-icons left">arrow_back_ios</i>
                            </a>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn orange darken-4 btn-info right">Confirmar
                                <i class="material-icons left">save</i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @else
                    <div class="row"></div>
                    <div class="row"></div>
                    <p> Desculpe! Página Indisponivel, Você não tem cadastro nessa instituição, Procure a secretaria e faça sua Matrícula </p>
                    <div class="row"></div>
                    <div class="row"></div>
                    <div class="row"></div>
                    <div class="row"></div>
                    <a title="Voltar Para Página Principal" class="btn orange darken-4 btn-info left " href="/admin">Voltar
                                <i class="material-icons left">arrow_back_ios</i>
                    </a>
                @endif



            </div>
        </div>    
    </form>
</div>
```

@endsection

Comment: JAVASCRIPT ou PHP ?

Comment: PHP mesmo porque laravel é só um framework

Comment: "só após reload", como assim men ?

Comment: quando a pagina recarrega.

Comment: humm entendi, é desse modo que faço ainda n mexo com javascript para fazer tudo sem precisar carregar a página :)

Comment: Como eu posso tratar o problema ?

Comment: o ideal é você dizer qual button quer alterar, onde quer que ele apareça. só com php eu nao tenho mérito a nao ser dentro do echo.

Comment: vou fazer 2 codigos de exemplo pra você ver

Comment: Blz, pode mudar o botão confirmar onde vai mudar "para inscrito" o local pode ser o mesmo lugar que estava mesmo

Comment: Blz mano ......

Comment: Eu vi no site e cadastrei um teste é desse jeito mesmo que queria, top

Comment: Com mensagem no botão

Comment: Você tem código de exemplo ?

Comment: descupe. nao vi quando disse que tinha acessado. ele é javascript. mais é bem simples. e pode ser reutilizado em muitos codigos ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Manda ai pra eu testar aqui

Comment: então você quer em javascript mesmo ?

Comment: Bora ver se vai funfar aqui sem problema rsrs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adicione isso aí ao seu arquivo de codigos do javascript,

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 //escolhendo o formulario pelo ID
$('#id_do_formulario').submit(function(e) {
 //evitando que a pagina seja recarregada
 e.preventDefault();
 //evita que o efeito caia sobre os objetos parentes
 e.stopPropagation();
  // iniciando requisição
    $.ajax({
     //define com GET OU POST de acordo com seu formulario.
        type: 'POST',
        //pégando o link de processamento
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        //pegando os campos do formulario
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        //escolhendo o tipo de dados recebido
        dataType: 'html',
        //Definindo resposta no cado de sucesso.
        success: function(data) {
         //ções caso a o processamento tenha dado certo
   $('#id_do_formulario').prepend(data);//adicionando resposta no formulario
   $('#id_button_submit').text('Novo texto do button');//mudando texto do buttan
   
        }
    })
    return false;
});
});
```

```html
> e isso, você adiciona no final do arquivo do formulario.

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: edite os campos eu marquei o ID e seja felix.